# E_NOTICE does not warn about unassigned values

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have E_NOTICE activated in php.ini. It still does not warn me about unassigned values like

```
$foo++;
```

Tried to set the error_reporting as well. Does not work. error_reporting() is set to 6143, which means that E_NOTICE is activated.
This code snippet also warns me with a notice:

```
$foo = bar;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem found: We do compile the php ourself and during this process unassigned variables notice is patched out. :-(

Answer (score 3):

That should cause an error message. Perhaps it is caused by registering an error handler which incorrectly swallows all errors? Such as

```
function error_handler($error_number  /*, ... */) {
    // do stuff...
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I do have in fact a registered error_handler. But even if I do not set the error_handler, I don't get a notice. Very strange.
I have php 5.2.10

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in PHP Version 5.2.8

> Notice: Undefined variable: foo

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);  // Also works with 6143
$foo++;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After altering the file php.ini. you should restart the php/apache services.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the PHP manual, you can also set them in your scripts (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php#refsect1-function.ini-set-examples):

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}
```

So, a complete error setting to have the maximum level of error reporting could be something as:

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$foo = bar;
```

Put this code at the beginning of your script and it'll show you all errors, notice and all the rest.